# $g_{\mu\nu}$ metric and Urbantke metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry

If $B^{IJ}=e^{I}\wedge e^{J}$, with $e^{I}$ the standard tetrad field, I need to prove that the expression \begin{equation}f_{ijk}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}B_{\mu\alpha}^{i}B_{\beta\gamma}^{j}B_{\delta\nu}^{k}\end{equation} is proportional to \begin{equation}e_{\mu}^{I}e_{\nu}^{J}\eta_{IJ},\end{equation} where $f_{ijk}$ are the structure constants of the Lie algebra of the Lorentz group.
My problem is that, even having the explicit value of $f_{ijk}$, I cannot find a way to transform the first expression into the second one.

Clearly $B$ is an element of $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$, so I write it as $B=B^{i}T_{i}$ where $T_{i}$ with $i=1,2,3$ are the generators of rotations, and $T_{i}$ with $i=4,5,6$ are the generators of boosts.

Considering the properties of $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$, I can prove that $B_{\mu\nu}^{i}=2e_{\mu}^{I}e_{\nu}^{J}(T^{j})_{JI}$. The indices $I, J,,\dots$ are internal indices, raised and lowered with $\eta_{IJ}$. $T_{i}$ are $6\times 6$ real matrices, and $(T_{i})_{~~K}^{I}$ is the $IK$ element of the matrix $T_{i}$, so, $(T_{i})^{IJ}=\eta^{JK}(T_{i})_{~~K}^{I}$

Using this result, I find that
$$f_{ijk}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}B_{\mu\alpha}^{i}B_{\beta\gamma}^{j}B_{\delta\nu}^{k}=8f_{ijk}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}e_{\mu}^{I}e_{\alpha}^{J}e_{\beta}^{M}e_{\gamma}^{L}e_{\delta}^{N}e_{\nu}^{P}(T^{i})_{JI}(T^{j})_{LM}(T^{k})_{PN}=\dfrac{8}{\sqrt{|g|}}f_{ijk}\epsilon^{JMLN}e_{\mu}^{I}e_{\nu}^{P}(T^{i})_{JI}(T^{j})_{LM}(T^{k})_{PN},$$ but I don't know how to continue.

I cannot find a way to recover the Minkowski's metric $\eta$ using $f_{ijk}$. Moreover, knowing the explicit value of $f_{ijk}$ seems not to be useful, but an identity for $f_{ijk}$.

Notice that the stardard expression $$[M^{\mu\nu},M^{\alpha\beta}]=M^{\mu\beta}\eta^{\nu\alpha}-\dots$$ seems not to be useful either, nor the expressions $[J_{i}, J_{j}]=\epsilon^{ijk}J_{k}
$, because of the way in which the generatos $T_{i}$ are being considered.

Comment: See if this paper is helpful [On the Relations between Gravity and BF Theories](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.763.9783&rep=rep1&type=pdf), namely (possibly) equation 4 and the paragraph below it. They are working with $SU(2)$ so you might have to go back through their work and pick up a factor of a half or so, or add some indices since $SO(3,1)\cong SU(2)\oplus SU(2)$. Hope this helps a bit.